# Add Marker in Angular-Google-Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently having some trouble adding a marker on click to Google Maps. I'm using http://angular-ui.github.io .

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events="map.events">
  <ui-gmap-marker coords="map.marker.coords" idKey="map.marker.id"></ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And there is my JS:

```
$scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: alat.value, longitude: alon.value },
        zoom: 15,
        streetViewControl: false,
        events: {
            click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
                $scope.map.marker = {
                    id: 1,
                    coords: {
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon
                    }
                };
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    };
```

I've been following the Angular-Google-Maps API, but I'm not entirely excellent at the Google Maps API as yet. So far, I've deduced that my click event does work, but my marker is not being added to the map. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have created the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sya8gn0w/1/). Here is the HTML.

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" events="map.events">
        <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in map.markers" coords="m.coords" icon="m.icon" idkey="m.id"></ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

The controller is like this.

```
angular.module('main', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    angular.extend($scope, {
        map: {
            center: {
                latitude: 42.3349940452867,
                longitude:-71.0353168884369
            },
            zoom: 11,
            markers: [],
            events: {
            click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
                var marker = {
                    id: Date.now(),
                    coords: {
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: lon
                    }
                };
                $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
                console.log($scope.map.markers);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I needed. I added $scope.map.markers.pop(); in there as well to limit the marker to just one.

Comment: Could you explain why this works? Why is `angular.extend()` used?

Comment: Can i add click="" in to   <ui-gmap-marker> directive?

Comment: <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in map.markers" coords="m.coords" icon="m.icon" idkey="m.id"></ui-gmap-marker click="open()">,but click() is not firing

Comment: I had the same issue when loading Marker information from Firebase. The trick was adding `$scope.$apply()` after adding the marker to the scope.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need give $scope.map.marker.id one init value. Otherwise, below error would occur.

gMarker.key undefined and it is REQUIRED!!